# Random Number Generation using LogNormalDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, random, distributions

I have a problem that I can't seem to figure out on my own due to limited knowledge of mathematics, and I was hoping I could seek help from the community. I would like to use `LogNormalDistribution` to generate random variables bound by min and max. I fail to do so, and I believe it is due to the way I derive `Mean` and `StandardDeviation`. Here is a simplified version of what I want to achieve but using a `UniformDistribution` instead.

```
size = 10^4; 
bound = {10^-7, 10^-4}; 

NumberLinePlot @ Interval @ bound
```

[image]

```
Histogram @ RandomVariate[UniformDistribution @ bound, size]
```

[image]

Based on the above, I can generate random numbers using an `UniformDistribution`. I have tried to derive a `PDF` for the above. However, it fails with an error message. Note, I use Win10 and Mathematica 11 for this work.

```
Show[
 Histogram[
   RandomVariate[UniformDistribution @ bound, size], 
   30, 
  "PDF"
 ],
 Plot[
  PDF[UniformDistribution @ bound, x], 
  {x, bound}
 ]
]
```

> Skeleton is not a Graphics primitive or directive.

What I would like to be able to do is generate random numbers within a pre-defined boundary using a `LogNormalDistribution`. I have tried to achieve it by exploring `Mean` and `StandardDeviation` functions. However, I fail to achieve the desired outcome. In terms of the `Mean`, I would like it to remain sloped to the left towards the min. However, it can be anywhere within the first 15% of the `CDF`.

I do appreciate your help, and thank you for your willingness to assist me with the above.

**EDIT 1 - `PDF` Fix for the above example, based on @kglr contribution**

```
Show[
  Histogram[
    RandomVariate[UniformDistribution@bound, size], 
    30, 
    "PDF"
  ],
  Plot[
    PDF[UniformDistribution@bound, x], 
    {x, ## & @@ bound}
  ]
]
```

Comment: try `Show[Histogram[RandomVariate[UniformDistribution@bound, size], 30, 
  "PDF"], Plot[PDF[UniformDistribution@bound, x], {x, ## & @@ bound}]]`?

Comment: Hello, @kglr, and thank you - this actually does work. I am not sure why; I will need to read-up about it.

Comment: e.doroskevis, correct syntax is `Plot[function[x],   {x, a, b}]` not `Plot[ function[x], {x, {a,b}}]` (this is what you have in your code). `{x, ##&@@round}` (or, equivalently, `{x, Sequence @@ round}`) gives  `{x, 10^-7, 10^-4`} which is the form `Plot` wants in its second argument.

Comment: Thank you, @kglr. I see what I did wrong.

Answer (score 1):

@Chris gave you most if not all that you needed.  Here is a follow-up to that answer:

```
dist = TruncatedDistribution[{xmin, xmax}, LogNormalDistribution[μ, σ]]
(* Mean  *)
mean = Simplify[Mean[dist], Assumptions -> {0 < xmin < xmax, σ > 0}]
```

[image: Mean]

```
(* 15th percentile  *)
x15 = Simplify[InverseCDF[dist, 15/100], Assumptions -> {0 < xmin < xmax, σ > 0, μ ∈ Reals}]
```

[image: 15th percentile]

You ask for determining the combination of parameters (`xmin`, `xmax`, `μ`, and `σ`) that result in `mean < x15`.  I don't think there are any combinations of the parameters that will result in that inequality being true.